# I have a charitable carryforward from 2011: Can I file in October 2017 (extension) and still take it?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, tax-deduction, charitable-contributions

In 2011, I made a large charitable contribution to my school.  Some is still left over, despite my having taken the maximum allowable charitable deduction each year.  I know that I cannot carryforward this deduction beyond 2016.

My question is: do I have to file my 2016 return by April 15, 2017 to take a  deduction for the 2011 contribution, or do I have until Oct 15, 2017 (after filing for an extension)?  (I am trying to plan a trip which, if I take it, will necessitate filing for an extension.)